# why does log4j output to stdout?

Tags: java, log4j

I have the following log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,A1,A2,A3

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.A1.File=log.out
log4j.appender.A1.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.A1.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %d %t %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.A2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A2.Threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.A2.File=warnings.out
log4j.appender.A2.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.A2.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.A2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A2.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %d %t %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.A3=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A3.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.A3.File=errors.out
log4j.appender.A3.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.A3.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.A3.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A3.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %d %t %c - %m%n
```

In my Java program, I have the following variable defined:

```
private Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();

static {
    URL url = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/log4j.properties");

    if (url == null) {
        // log4j.properties not found in CLASSPATH, revert to console output
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
    }
    else {
        // log4j.properties found
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(url);
    }
}
```

Why is it when I call the logger methods, the output also goes to the console (stdout), in addition to the 3 output files?

Comment: Are you certain that it's going to stdout, and not stderr? The latter would be easier to account for.

Comment: How are you packaging the log4j file? Do you have the `-Dlog4j.configuration` set to the correct file when starting your JVM?

Comment: @ruakh it's possible that it could be going to stderr... either way it's going to the console and I'm not sure why...

Comment: If it's going to stderr -- which you can easily check, by running the program with `>stdout-goes-here 2>stderr-goes-here` to redirect stout and stderr to separate files -- then the next thing to look at is: is it going to `log.out`? Because if it's going to stderr and *not* `log.out`, then probably your configuration-file simply isn't taking effect.

Comment: @ruakh i have confirmed that everything is going to stdout. when i redirected stderr to a file, the file was empty.  also, log4j seems to recognize the properties file because it does generate the 3 output files i configured in the properties file

Comment: Are you sure it's creating them? They weren't there before? I think there is a chance that log4j is finding the file and loading it by default, then Java's classloader for your class doesn't find it, so you call BasicConfigurator.configure(), overriding your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to name your file log4j.properties and put it in the root of your classpath, then it will be picked up by default, you don't need to pass it to BasicConfigurator.

What is probably happening in your case is that Java's classloader is not finding the file there (on the root), your call to BasicConfigurator.configure() without parameters is getting log4j to use the default configuration.

Make sure log4j.properties is a the root of your war file's classpath, i.e.:

`WEB-INF\classes\log4j.properties`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue by removing the entire static block. For some odd reason, BasicConfigurator.configure() seems to be getting called... (even though the other 3 files are being generated as well)

Comment: IMHO, classloaders and their classpaths are some of the hardest things to predict in J2EE environments. It takes some trial and error. I think the files were being created because log4j found and loaded its configuration file, but then your code overrode it and loaded an empty configuration. Also IMHO, it's best to just let log4j find the file in the default location and do its thing, without calling a configurator in the code.